# Intellij Idea debugging an application stepping fails and application terminate

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm going crazy with this.

Suppose you're debugging an application and it just stopped on a breakpoint, 
the next line does nothing strange let's say create a new class, 
all is wrapped in a try catch(Exception e)
you then press step into or step over button
the application then terminate and the debugger tell you "frame not available"
The console report "Process finished with exit code 0"

What's wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, found the problem, the main thread exited and there were only daemon threads, so the VM simply exited during debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem, the main thread exited and there were only daemon threads, so the VM simply exited during debug